# RxSwift+Moya+Moya_ObjectMapper+MJRefresh, refresh failed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, moya

I'm newer to RxSwift. **I want to refresh the tableview to show new data**.The first request that I can get the data. but when I pull down the tableview, the request didn't finished. I have no ideas about this? My code is belowing:

1: My viewController's code:

```
class RecommendViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var tableView = DefaultManager.createTableView(HomeImageCell.self, 
                                                    HomeImageCell.idenfitier)
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
lazy var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
lazy var dataSource: [HomeListDetailModel] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel.fetchRecommendList("answer_feed",0)
    setupTableView()
    configureRefresh()
    bindDataToTableView()
}

func setupTableView() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalTo(0)
    }
    tableView.estimatedHeight(200)
}

func bindDataToTableView() {
    viewModel.recommend
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .do(onNext: { [unowned self] model in
            print("endAllRefresh")
            self.endAllRefresh()
        }, onError: { (error) in
            self.endAllRefresh()
            print("error = \(error)")
        })
        .map { [unowned self] model in
            return self.handleData(model)
        }.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: HomeImageCell.idenfitier , cellType: HomeImageCell.self )) { index, model, cell in
            cell.updateCell(data: model)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

func configureRefresh() {
    tableView.mj_header = MJRefreshNormalHeader(refreshingBlock: { [unowned self] in
        let model = self.dataSource[0]
        self.viewModel.fetchRecommendList("answer_feed",model.behot_time)

    })
    tableView.mj_footer = MJRefreshAutoNormalFooter(refreshingBlock: { [unowned self] in
        let model = self.dataSource[self.dataSource.count - 1]
        self.viewModel.fetchRecommendList("answer_feed",model.behot_time)
    })
}

func endAllRefresh() {
    self.tableView.mj_header.endRefreshing()
    self.tableView.mj_footer.endRefreshing()
}

func handleData(_ model: HomeListModel) -> [HomeListDetailModel] {
    guard let data = model.detailData else {
        return dataSource
    }
    self.dataSource = data
    return data
}
}
```

2: My ViewModel

```
protocol HomeProtocol {
    func fetchRecommendList(_ category: String, _ behot_time: Int) 
}

class HomeViewModel: HomeProtocol  {
    lazy var provider = HTTPServiceProvider.shared
    var recommend: Observable<HomeListModel>!

    init() {}

    init(_ provider: RxMoyaProvider<MultiTarget>) {
       self.provider = provider
    }

    func fetchRecommendList(_ category: String, _ behot_time: Int) {
        recommend = provider.request(MultiTarget(HomeAPI.homeList(category: category,behot_time: behot_time)))
        .debug()
        .mapObject(HomeListModel.self)
    } 
 }
```

When I made a breakpoint at request method, it didn't do a request? Does anyone know it ? Thanks first

Answer (score 0):

SomeOne told me the reason,So I write it here. In my ViewModel `recommend` should be backed by `PublishSubject` or `BehaviourSubject` or `ReplaySubject` and then I should share this for `View` as `Observable`. In  `fetchRecommentList` method I should bind request to created `Subject`.
Now I have created observable, but request will run after `subsribe` or `bind`